# Why Can't I Access all WAR Package files from it's root?

Tags: javascript, include, war

I know I should be able to reference all files in a WAR file app from the WAR root '/'.  But it doesn't seem to work. And I'm really stumped.

My app deploys its web content in the following WAR file.

```
WAR
  index.html
  META-INF
  WEB-INF
  css
    fonts.css
    other style  sheets
  images
    Banner.jpg
  jsp-pages
    headers
      beg.jsp
      menu.jsp
      end.jsp
    level-1
      pages
        anypage.jsp
        multiple subdirectories
          multipe subdirecories
  scripts
    multiple scripts
```

My app has have hundreds of html pages in different levels of the WAR directory. And they all need to reference images, css files, script files, and other html pages a different directory levels.

Therefore, I'd dearly love to be able to reference all files from the WAR root '/'. (So I don't have to count the number of '../' I need every time.

I know this should let me link this style sheet from any file at any level:

```
<link href="/css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

But it doesn't work so I have to use relative referring.

```
<link href="../../../css/fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Even worse. It doesn't seem to be consistent.

For example,   All html files in WAR/jsp-pages/level-1/pages are structured this way.

```
<%@ include file='/jsp-pages/level-1/headers/beg.jsp'%>
content
<%@ include file='/jsp-pages/level-1/headers/end.jsp' %>
```

And this is the beg.jsp code. So please note that I can reference the include inside beg.jsp from the WEB root '/'.  But I have to reference the image relative to the page's folder.

**beg.jsp**

```
<html>
  <head>
    the css link above
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="banner">
      <!-- this needed a relative reference -->
      <img style="width:100%"      src='../../../images/Banner.jpg'/>
      <!-- but I could reference this include from '/' -->
      <%@ include file='/jsp-pages/level-1/headers/menu.jsp' %>
      <!--        Every page must close with         -->
      <!--       </div> For: class='content-block'>  -->
      <!--     </div> For: class='scroll-block'>     -->
      <!--   </body>                                 -->
      <!-- </html>                                   -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is so simple it's embarrassing.

And kind of disappointing no one offered it.

If you deploy an app with

```
  <web>
    <web-uri>Pct109.war</web-uri>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
  </web>
```

I.e. so the app opens with just http://domanName.org/

Then you can reference all war files with "/"

But if you want to deploy many apps under the same domain, and give all apps with a deeper context, with something like

```
  <web>
    <web-uri>Pct109.war</web-uri>
    <context-root>/Pct109</context-root>
  </web>
```

I.e. so it opens with http://domanName.org/Pct109, you can reference all war files with /Pct109/

Obvious ... grin ... once you figure it out.

The war files are referenced from how you deploy them 
... not just from the the top of the war package

Happy Trails.